# Best match of a numeric sequence

Tags: pattern-matching, numeric

I am trying to find the best way to match a user generated sequence of numbers against a predefined sequence. For example, I have the sequences 1,2,3,4 and 4,3,2,1, The user can generate a sequence using any of those numbers (including omitting some) e.g. 2,3,4 / 4,3,1 / 1,2,3,2,1. 
I'm thinking about assigning a score based on the difference of each number in the sequence but I'm not sure if there's a more optimal solution.

Comment: why is 4 3 1 valid? and what stops someone from choosing 1234321234321234 ...

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking from your description and example and proposed solution. What would an optimal matching mean, and if you assigned a score to it, how would that score be defined?

Comment: The idea is that there may not be an exact match to the sequence but that the closest value would match. So for the sequence 1,2,3,4; 1,2,4 would rank higher than 4,3,2,1 because even though a digit in the sequence was missing, the rest of them were in order. It's trying to determine what route was taken from GPS checkpoints given that some of the checkpoints may have been missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look up dynamic time warping for one possible solution, see e.g. en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping. Note that a numeric sequence can be regarded as a time series, and also you can align two sequences by multiplying the "time" index by a scalar multiple so that the two sequences have the same start and end time. Or you can just leave the time index equal to the sequence index without scaling.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I'm after. Thanks very much.